# Sending multiple, individual emails, different subject, different message

Tags: php, arrays, email, foreach, implode

I've been trying to get my head round this and it's proving impossible for me to figure out, I'm pretty new to PHP as you can tell.

I have myself three arrays which I implode(','$array) and I'm trying to send out an email using the email address from one array, a name as a subject from another array, and the name from another array as the message. Can this be done?

I've tried it myself with the below code but the emails that get sent out share the same information as the other emails.

I think I need to do a foreach() to run through the three arrays but not quite sure how to do it. Any tips?

```
$to      = implode(',',$name_email_pair);
$message = implode(',',$match);
$subject = implode(',',$inorder);
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";    
$headers .= 'From: example@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: example@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
//header("Location: thankyou.php");  
echo "<br>WORKS"; 
?>

Array (Size=3) //$name_email_pair
'Joe' => String 'Example1@Example.Com' (Length=20)
'Dave' => String 'Example2@Example.Com' (Length=20)
'Ben' => String 'Example3@Example.Com' (Length=20)

Array (Size=3) //$inorder
0 => String 'Joe' (Length=3)
1 => String 'Dave' (Length=4)
2 => String 'Ben' (Length=3)

Array (Size=3) //$match
0 => String 'Ben' (Length=3)
1 => String 'Joe' (Length=3)
2 => String 'Dave' (Length=4)
```

Comment: show all your arrays

Comment: Why, yes. You're sending *one* email which has all this information combined. If you want to send *three separate emails*, you need to call `mail()` three times with different information...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you try to achieve?

```
 for($i=0;$i<count($name_email_pair);$i++)
    {
        $to      = $name_email_pair[$i];
        $message = $match[$i];
        $subject = $inorder[$i];
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";    
        $headers .= 'From: example@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: example@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
    //header("Location: thankyou.php");  
    echo "<br>WORKS";
```

If not then show us they arrays content so i can edit the answer.

Comment: I've added the arrays, I'll try this code in the meanwhile thanks

Answer (score 0):

> STOP
>
> You don't need to implode, you are going right

Steps to do

1. Get array size in this case 3 ;) <-- for you
2. use for-each on the array
3. send mail

It is indeed easy for you now that

```
foreach($mailing_credentials as $key=>$val){

// Mailing codes e.g. subject, cc, bcc etc
// Send Individual Mails

}
```

I never meant to be rude, it is just the fun way for me to express :)
Happy Coding !